# Options of bootstrap-select not displayed in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I added a language selector to my Angular app using **bootstrap-select**. It used to work in the past, but after a browser update the select element is no longer visible. I only see the label with no options.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="language_select">Language:</label>
    <select id="language_select" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
      <option value="en" data-content="<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-gb'></span> English"></option>
      <option value="de" data-content="<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-de'></span> Deutsch"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any known issue when using **bootstrap-select** with Angular? Even without any data binding, the select box is not displayed.

I'm using:

- jQuery 1.12.4
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- bootstrap-select 1.12.2
- Angular 1.4.7

Comment: There is no AngularJS handling inside your template. It's bootstrap only.

Comment: It's bad practise to mix jQuery, bootstrap and AngularJS.

Comment: I know, even if I remove all data bindings, the select box is not rendered. Seems like something is interfering here.

Comment: Did  you checked the console? Any errors? Are all ressources loaded correctly? Have you checked the rendered dom -> Is your select HTML inside?

Comment: Console checked, no errors. Resources loaded and select box is included in the DOM, though ``display: none!important;`` is set for ``select.selectpicker`` and options are not visible, if value is altered.

Comment: Allright. thx. Could you please create a plnkr or fiddle reproduce it? Well, if `select.selectpicker` was set to `display:none` this should be your reason, isnt it =) ?

Comment: This is the initial visibility set by bootstrap-select.js on default.

Comment: Please create a fiddle or plnkr so.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QPz6LN3fgF2jmOnivMLc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146633/discussion-between-lin-and-user1438038).

Comment: Please join me in chat m8 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

The Angular extension **[nya-bootstrap-select](http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/)** solved the problem for me. The module has no dependencies to external JavaScript files and overcomes the issue of different concepts within Angular and jQuery (data binding vs. event-driven).

---

## Detailed answer

It turned out that using Angular and jQuery (which is required by Bootstrap) is widely discouraged, due to the [different concepts of both libraries](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together) (data binding vs. event-driven). So eventually, directly using **bootstrap-select** within my Angular application is not an option.

There is an Angular extension called **[angular-bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select)** that tries to overcome this technical issue. However, the GitHub project is marked as `DEPRECATED`.

I found a fork called **[ng-bootstrap-select](https://github.com/caseyjhol/ng-bootstrap-select)**, which is still being maintained. Though, I did not have a closer look at that project.

Instead I am using **[nya-bootstrap-select](http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/)** now, which is another Angular extension. It is loosely based on the initial **bootstrap-select** implementation, but has no dependencies to neither jQuery nor Bootstrap's JavaScript code. You only need to include the Bootstrap CSS file.

---

My code looks somewhat like this now:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="language_select">Language:</label>
    <ol id="language_select" class="nya-bs-select">
      <li class="nya-bs-option" value="en">
        <a><span class="dummy-wrapper"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span> English</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nya-bs-option" value="de">
        <a><span class="dummy-wrapper"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"></span> Deutsch</span></a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

The combobox is initialized right from the start, picking a different item immediately toggles the language and the current user language is pre-selected automatically, when loading the page for the very first time.